# Wizard for New Volume from Cluster Pool shows 0.00 GB free (despite 1.50 TB in Server Manager)

Tags: failovercluster, virtual-disk, storage-spaces-direct

So an issue I am running into is that I have a Storage Pool using S2D created, it shows less than 2 GB used up... but when I go to run the virtual disk wizard, it has Free Space: 0.00 GB for both performance and capacity tier.  Due to this, Any value I specify says it goes beyond the available resources.

Do they need to be formatted?  Do I need to run some other powershell command to make them do their thing?

[Virtual disk wizard Free space 0.00 GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H20Kg.png)

Comment: Did you configure S2D properly? Do you have the same (and enough!) amount of disks added to S2D pool on each node? How many nodes / disks / SSDs do you have?

Comment: 4 disks, 1 per node, all VHDDs.  I ended up removing them all and re-adding them again (didn't change the setup) and creating the pool on a different VM using powershell.

Command was (paraphrased)
New-Volume -FriendlyName "ClustervDisk0" -FileSystem CSVFS_ReFS -StoragePoolFriendlyName Cluster* -usemaximumsize -ResiliencySettingName Parity -PhysicalDiskRedundancy 2

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using powershell on a different machine in the cluster after removing and re-adding the VHDs:

```powershell
New-Volume -FriendlyName "ClustervDisk0" -FileSystem CSVFS_ReFS -StoragePoolFriendlyName Cluster* -usemaximumsize -ResiliencySettingName Parity -PhysicalDiskRedundancy 2
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how much this will help others because it might be very specific to my installation.  The command above was for 2 500GB VHDDs and 2 250GB VHDDs, with 1 drive per cluster node.